# Is it possible to infer one type in c# and specify another?

Tags: c#, list, generics, type-conversion, ienumerable

Suppose you have a list class like

```
class Words : List<Word>
{
  ...
}
```

and suppose you want to create one of these from an `IEnumerable<Word>` with a function like:

```
public static TList ToTypedList<TList, T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
where TList : IList<T>, new()
{
  var listTyped = new TList();

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
     listTyped.Add(item);
  }

  return listTyped;
}
```

so that you can write:

```
Words words = someEnumerableOfWords.ToTypedList<Words, Word>();
```

It seems redundant to have to specify the `Word` type parameter, since `someEnumerableOfWords` is  already of type `IEnumerable<Word>` and could be inferred, but doing, say, this:

```
Words words = someEnumerableOfWords.ToTypedList<Words>();
```

causes a compiler error.

Is there any way to accomplish the kind of type inference that I'm looking for?

**Update**: To clarify why I want to do this, it's not just about saving a few characters while typing, but also have a chainable, fluid interface:

```
var result = object.Child.MethodThatOutputsWords().ToTypedList<Words>().DoSomethingWithTheWords().DoSomethingElse();
```

The suggestion to just make another constructor that takes the list of words isn't perfect because it would require

```
var result = new Words(object.Child.MethodThatOutputsWords()).DoSomethingWithTheWords().DoSomethingElse();
```

and I find that much harder to read, because you can't just scan left to right, as in the first example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code read quickly, but why not just use LINQ [ConvertAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555661/convert-list-of-one-type-to-list-of-another-type-in-c-sharp-3-5) or [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075572/using-linq-to-convert-listu-to-listt) or [Cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/shorter-syntax-for-casting-from-a-listx-to-a-listy) depending on the case?

Comment: Assuming there is a way to create a `Words` from a `List<Word>` (possibly a constructor?) then why not do it after the fact?  `new Words(someEnumerableOfWords.ToList())`

Comment: I'd say you should [favour composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) here and `words` should **contain** a List. Makes everything much easier.

Comment: @Wyck: I just like fluent and chainable interfaces. I might want to do `...ToList().DoSomething().DoSomethingElse()`, and having to use `new Words()` as a containing construction is harder to read, IMO.

Comment: @Liam: I've read that thread many times and I agree with much of it. But sometimes `Words` really is just a `List<Word>`, and I want to have a `Words` class mostly as an alias, and then I don't have to implement `IList<T>` in every such list class.

Comment: For an alias, consider `using Words = System.Collections.Generic.List<YourNamespace.Word>;`

Comment: @Wyck: That's good, but the `using` statement needs to be written in every single file in the project that needs the alias, which is really inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, there is no way to use only one type parameter and keep type safety (excluding solutions using Reflection).

Just add a constructor to the `Words` class having an `IEnumerable<Word>` parameter and pass it to the base constructor (`List<T>` happens to have such a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0)):

```cs
class Words : List<Word>
{
    public Words(IEnumerable<Word> words)
        : base(words)
    {
    }

    public Words() // Default constructor, allows you to create an empty list.
    {
    }
}
```

Then

```cs
var words = new Words(someEnumerableOfWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Olivier, that's the cleanest way. But if you would insist on a general extension method, you'll lose the type check for the inner elements. Try this:

```
public static TList ToTypedList<TList>(this IEnumerable list) where TList : IList, new()
{
    TList result = new TList();
    
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        result.Add(element);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `element` is typed as `object`. You will need a cast to `T`.

Comment: No you don't, because generic constraint is IList. Check this out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lOQL8r

Comment: Okay, you are right, but you are giving up type safety, which generics is all about.

Comment: Yep, that's why I warned him. You can probably do some manual type check. I've told him your solution is cleaner, but you never know maybe he needs more general solution.